# Immeasurable Pathological Sets

Tags: probability, measure-theory

When discussing the extension of measure in any standard measure theory setting, the argument for having the minimal sigma algebra is to minimize the possibility that it includes pathological sets which (probability) measure cannot be assigned.

Can someone give an example plus intuitive explanation for why it is not a "good fit" for the purpose of constructing probability measure to go beyond (i.e.larger than) the sigma algebra generated by the typical class? What are some pathological cases?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/why-do-we-need-sigma-algebras-to-define-probability-spaces) answers your question, but interesting nonetheless